# Form with ManyToMany with attributes

Tags: forms, symfony, attributes, many-to-many

I currently have two entities ManyToMany with attributes.
I am creating my project creation form.
I wish I could select with checkboxes, categories of my recipe.
My problem is that I have the fields in my form but data processing do not work! The association between my recipe and my classes do not work.
Sorry if I inconsistencies in the variables. I changed the variable names and namespaces.

**Project :**

```
<?php

namespace Test\Bundle\ProjectBundle\Entity;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Project
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="project")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Test\Bundle\ProjectBundle\Entity\ProjectRepository")
 */
class Project
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /** 
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Test\Bundle\ProjectBundle\Entity\CategoryProject", mappedBy="projects")
     */
    protected $categoryprojects;
}
```

?>

**Category:**

```
<?php

namespace Test\Bundle\ProjectBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Category
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="category")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Test\Bundle\ProjectBundle\Entity\CategoryRepository")
 */
class Category
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /** 
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Test\Bundle\ProjectBundle\Entity\CategoryProject", mappedBy="categories")
     */
    protected $categoryprojects;

}
?>
```

**CategoryProject**

```
<?php

namespace Test\Bundle\ProjectBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * AppMonde
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="categoryProject")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class CategoryProject
{

    /** 
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Test\Bundle\ProjectBundle\Entity\Category", inversedBy="categoryprojects") 
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false) 
     */
    protected $categories;

    /** 
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Test\Bundle\ProjectBundle\Entity\Project", inversedBy="categoryprojects") 
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="project_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false) 
     */
    protected $projects;

        /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="booleanos", type="boolean")
     */
    protected $booleanos;


    /**
     * Set a category
     *
     * @param \Test\Bundle\ProjectBundle\Entity\Category $category
     * @return User
     */
    public function addCategory(\Test\Bundle\ProjectBundle\Entity\Category $category)
    {
        $this->categories[] = $category;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove a category
     *
     * @param \Test\Bundle\ProjectBundle\Entity\Category $category
     */
    public function removeCategory($category)
    {
        return $this->category->removeElement($category);
    }

    /**
     * Get categories
     *
     * @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getCategories()
    {
        return $this->categories;
    }

    /**
     * Set a project
     *
     * @param \Test\Bundle\ProjectBundle\Entity\Project $project
     * @return User
     */
    public function addProject(\Test\Bundle\ProjectBundle\Entity\Project $project)
    {
        $this->projects[] = $project;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove a project
     *
     * @param \Test\Bundle\ProjectBundle\Entity\Project $project
     */
    public function removeProject($project)
    {
        return $this->projects->removeElement($project);
    }

    /**
     * Remove all projects
     *
     * @param \Test\Bundle\ProjectBundle\Entity\Project $project
     */
    public function removeAllProjects()
    {
        $this->projects->clear();
    }

    /**
     * Get projects
     *
     * @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getProjects()
    {
        return $this->projects;
    }
}
?>
```

**ProjectType**

```
<?php

namespace Test\Bundle\ProjectBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class ProjectType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title', 'text', array(
                'label' => 'Titre de l\'APP'
            ))
            ->add('resume', 'textarea', array(
                'label' => 'Résumé du projet et des actions prévues'
            ))
            ->add('categoryprojects', new CategortyProjectType(), array(
                'label' => '&nbsp;'
            ))
    }

}
?>
```

**CategortyProjectType**

```
<?php

namespace Test\Bundle\ProjectBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class CategoryProjectType extends AbstractType
{
        /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('categories', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'TestProjectBundle:Category',
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => true,
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('a')
                        ->where('a.type = :type')
                        ->setParameter('type', 'APP');
                },
                'label' => 'Le projet s\'inscrit-il dans le cadre d\'une APP Monde? Précisez laquelle',
            ))
        ;
    }

?>
```

**Error**

> Neither the property "categories" nor one of the methods
>   "getCategories()", "isCategories()", "hasCategories()", "__get()"
>   exist and have public access in class
>   "Aefe\Bundle\ProjectBundle\Entity\Category".

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer:

If i remember correctly, your entity needs to have an ID column, and only one.

Try this, and see if it helps:

```
<?php

namespace Test\Bundle\ProjectBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * AppMonde
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="categoryProject")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class CategoryProject
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /** 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Test\Bundle\ProjectBundle\Entity\Category", inversedBy="categoryprojects") 
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false) 
     */
    protected $categories;

    /** 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Test\Bundle\ProjectBundle\Entity\Project", inversedBy="categoryprojects") 
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="project_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false) 
     */
    protected $projects;
```

Comment: I have my getters and setters my, I did not set the example.

Comment: Ah alright :-) I looked at your relationships, and they look abit off. Please see my updated answer, and see if it helps.

Comment: I have no problem with the entities in my database. This is my (form + twig) that is the problem :s